# Set default timeZone in a combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, timezone

I would like to set my computer's current timezone as the default entry to a combobox containing all the timezones of the the world. How should i do this? Any Suggestions?

Comment: You can get the user's current timezone in JS using `new Date().toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1);`.  To get a list of time zones, you could use `moment.tz.names();` in the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var current_timezone = new Date().toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1);

Ext.getCmp('comboBoxID').setValue(current_timezone);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Z');
```